# How do I get a count of IDs based on if they meet certain criteria/outcome?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm faced with the following issue in Excel.  I want to get a count of students who failed 100% of their classes (earned either a D, F, No pass, or Withdrew) that they enrolled in during a semester.  What is a formula that can help count this?

The data is organized as the following:

[image: ExcelData]

I tried IF statements but I'm having trouble writing a formula that takes into account the condition that the student would need to have failed ALL of their classes that they enrolled in.  Some students enrolled in just one course and others enrolled in several.

I could manually count this but this would take too long considering there are over 15,000 rows of data.

I'm hoping to get a count of students who meet this requirement among 6,000 students (15,000 rows of data).

Any help is much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I think you're looking for `COUNTIFS`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A2:A14,A2:A14)=COUNTIFS(A2:A14,A2:A14,E2:E14,"Unsuccessful"))/COUNTIF(A2:A14,A2:A14))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a round about way, but I ended up recoding SCC where successful=1 and unsuccessful=0, then made a pivot table that gave me the sum of SCC with student IDs as my rows. I just sorted the Sum of the values and counted those with 0s, which gave me what I am looking for.

Hope this helps